# Can't boot CentOS 7 on USB (not live-usb) on Lenovo ideapad 710S

Tags: centos, boot, usb, bios

So I got a USB that got CentOS 7 installed (not live-USB) and as I can boot on my home's computer it can't boot on my `Lenovo IdeaPad 710s` laptop. I got no idea why, I've disabled secure boot at BIOS and the CentOS installer (DVD iso on USB) can boot successfully, why a normal CentOS 7 USB can't boot? Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried enabling secure boot and changing to UEFI instead of legacy boot?

Comment: @NasirRiley Won't changing to legacy crash the original Windows 10?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you change to UEFI. Not legacy.

Comment: @NasirRiley It's already in UEFI mode.

Comment: When you installed CentOS 7 on the USB, was it in legacy or UEFI?

Comment: @NasirRiley Not sure you meant the BIOS setting of the PC I use to install centos?

Comment: Yes. Was it UEFI or legacy?

Comment: @NasirRiley Not sure PC isn't beside me I'll check while get back, so if it's legacy I should reinstall the centos on a UEFI computer in order to boot on my laptop?

Comment: You will need to set the BIOS of the computer where you are trying to boot from USB to what it was on the computer where you installed CentOS or else it won't boot.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nasic Riley pointed out, you need to change your BIOS settings depending on how you installed CentOS, either in Legacy or UEFI. It seems like you installed your CentOS in Legacy boot mode, as you cannot boot into it while being in UEFI mode.

Changing your boot options to Legacy won't crash Windows. Windows will just not boot, instead your CentOS will boot.

If you are lazy and don't want to reinstall in UEFI mode, you can just switch boot mode every time you want to login to either OS(depending on ofcourse if your USB with your CentOS installation is plugged in). Doing so will do no damage to either OS.

However it is better if you install all your operating systems in UEFI as it has a lot of useful features. A simple Google on the difference between UEFI and Legacy should show you what you need to know.

Comment: How about will there be any difference in the data structure? Since I'm planning to backup with the instruction provided [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/114945-centos-7-backup-and-restore) and I was wondering if I backup like this will it be able to restore after I re-install centos 7 with UEFI mode?